# An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in WindowsApplication3.exe

Tags: vb.net

I need help trying to figure out what I am doing wrong... I try to debug but it keeps saying:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in WindowsApplication3.exe

Here is the code:

```
Public Class Form2
Public Sub New()
    MoveToStart()

    ' This call is required by the designer.
    InitializeComponent()

    ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.

End Sub
Private Sub Finish_MouseEnter(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    MessageBox.Show("Congratulations!")
    Close()
End Sub
Private Sub MoveToStart()
    Dim StartingPoint = Panel1.Location()
    StartingPoint.Offset(10, 10)
    Cursor.Position = PointToScreen(StartingPoint)

End Sub

Private Sub Wall_MouseEnter(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Label2.MouseEnter, Panel1.MouseEnter, Label9.MouseEnter, Label8.MouseEnter, Label7.MouseEnter, Label6.MouseEnter, Label56.MouseEnter, Label55.MouseEnter, Label54.MouseEnter, Label53.MouseEnter, Label52.MouseEnter, Label51.MouseEnter, Label50.MouseEnter, Label5.MouseEnter, Label49.MouseEnter, Label48.MouseEnter, Label47.MouseEnter, Label46.MouseEnter, Label45.MouseEnter, Label44.MouseEnter, Label43.MouseEnter, Label42.MouseEnter, Label41.MouseEnter, Label40.MouseEnter, Label4.MouseEnter, Label39.MouseEnter, Label38.MouseEnter, Label37.MouseEnter, Label36.MouseEnter, Label35.MouseEnter, Label34.MouseEnter, Label33.MouseEnter, Label32.MouseEnter, Label31.MouseEnter, Label30.MouseEnter, Label3.MouseEnter, Label29.MouseEnter, Label28.MouseEnter, Label27.MouseEnter, Label26.MouseEnter, Label25.MouseEnter, Label24.MouseEnter, Label23.MouseEnter, Label22.MouseEnter, Label21.MouseEnter, Label20.MouseEnter, Label19.MouseEnter, Label18.MouseEnter, Label17.MouseEnter, Label16.MouseEnter, Label15.MouseEnter, Label14.MouseEnter, Label13.MouseEnter, Label12.MouseEnter, Label11.MouseEnter, Label10.MouseEnter, Label1.MouseEnter, Finish.MouseEnter
    MoveToStart()


End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: VB.NET is nowhere near C++.

Comment: What is this question to do with C++?

Comment: Sorry, didn't realize I did that

Comment: Have you tried putting `MoveToStart()` after `InitializeComponent()` in the constructor?

Comment: @Tim is right. You're trying to access controls on a form before they've been initialised

Comment: That didn't work...Maybe there's something I'm forgetting to mention....I don't think I'm being detailed enough...Here's a screen-capture video of my project....Maybe that will help somewhat I hope. Here's a link to my video at youtube: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h8YUCpfC8co&feature=youtu.be

Comment: @5uperdan I've tried what you suggested but it keeps saying the same thing. Is there any other info I can give you to help explain the problem a little better? I have a link to youtube that I posted up showing my project/code etc...Not sure if that would help.